# "Conflicting requirements" for lifetime of item of iterator passed as parameter to method

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to get this code to compile:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone)]
struct Key<'a> {
    v: &'a str
}

fn make_key_iter(s: &str) -> Box<Iterator<Item = Key>> {
    Box::new(s.split('.').map(|e| Key { v: e }))
}

struct Node<'a> {
    children: HashMap<Key<'a>, Box<Node<'a>>>
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn lookup<'b>(&self, mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = Key<'b>>>) -> bool {
        match iter.next() {
            Some(key) => match self.children.get(&key) {
                             Some(node) => node.lookup(iter),
                             None => false
                         },
            None => true
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "a.b.c.d".to_string();
    let iter = make_key_iter(s.as_slice());
    let node = Node { children: HashMap::new() };
    node.lookup(iter);
}
```

[Playpen link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3AHashMap%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(PartialEq%2C%20Eq%2C%20Hash%2C%20Clone)%5D%0Astruct%20Key%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20v%3A%20%26%27a%20str%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20make_key_iter(s%3A%20%26str)%20-%3E%20Box%3CIterator%3CItem%20%3D%20Key%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew(s.split(%27.%27).map(%7Ce%7C%20Key%20%7B%20v%3A%20e%20%7D))%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Node%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20children%3A%20HashMap%3CKey%3C%27a%3E%2C%20Box%3CNode%3C%27a%3E%3E%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Node%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20lookup%3C%27b%3E(%26self%2C%20mut%20iter%3A%20Box%3CIterator%3CItem%20%3D%20Key%3C%27b%3E%3E%3E)%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20iter.next()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(key)%20%3D%3E%20match%20self.children.get(%26key)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(node)%20%3D%3E%20node.lookup(iter)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20s%20%3D%20%22a.b.c.d%22.to_string()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20iter%20%3D%20make_key_iter(s.as_slice())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20node%20%3D%20Node%20%7B%20children%3A%20HashMap%3A%3Anew()%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node.lookup(iter)%3B%0A%7D)

Compiling that gives the following error:

```
<anon>:18:20: 18:26 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
<anon>:18         match iter.next() {
                         ^~~~~~
<anon>:17:5: 25:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn lookup(&self, mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = Key<'b>>>) -> bool
```

What's really confusing is that the signature the compiler suggests is invalid altogether because it uses an undefined lifetime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, one suggestion: Since a boxed iterator is also an iterator, you can change your lookup function to

```
fn lookup<'b, I: Iterator<Item = Key<'b>>>(&self, mut iter: I) -> bool {
    match iter.next() {
        Some(key) => match self.children.get(&key) {
                         Some(node) => node.lookup(iter),
                         None => false
                     },
        None => true
    }
}
```

which is a bit more general. But the problem still persists. You're trying to pass a `&Key<'b>` in `self.children.get(&key)` to the HashMap which actually expects a `&Q` where `Q` implements `BorrowFrom<Key<'a>>`. The compiler's suggestion is now to replace `'b` with `'a` like this:

```
fn lookup<I: Iterator<Item = Key<'a>>>(&self, mut iter: I) -> bool { //'
    match iter.next() {
        Some(key) => match self.children.get(&key) {
                         Some(node) => node.lookup(iter),
                         None => false
                     },
        None => true
    }
}
```

which surely will make the compiler happy. But this is not really what you want! It would unnecessarily restrict the set of string slices you could use as parameters for your lookup. This way, you can only use string slices which refer to memory that is at least as long-lived as the scope that `'a` is referring to. But for a lookup this restriction is not actually needed.

The solution is to completely get rid of any lifetime parameters in the type parameter `Q` of the HashMap's `get` function. Instead of using `Q=Key<'something>`, we can actually use `Q=str`. We just need to add the following `BorrowFrom` implementation

```
impl<'a> BorrowFrom<Key<'a>> for str {
    fn borrow_from<'s>(owned: &'s Key<'a>) -> &'s str {
        owned.v
    }
}
```

and make the `Key` type public (since it's used as parameter in a public trait). The lookup function that worked for me looks like this:

```
fn lookup_iter<'b, I: Iterator<Item = Key<'b>>>(&self, mut i: I) -> bool {
    if let Some(key) = i.next() {
        match self.children.get(key.v) {
            Some(node_box_ref) => node_box_ref.lookup_iter(i),
            None => false
        }
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

And if we piece everything together, we get

```
#![feature(core)]
#![feature(hash)]
#![feature(std_misc)]
#![feature(collections)]

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::{ Occupied, Vacant };
use std::borrow::BorrowFrom;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone)]
pub struct Key<'a> {
    v: &'a str
}

impl<'a> BorrowFrom<Key<'a>> for str {
    fn borrow_from<'s>(owned: &'s Key<'a>) -> &'s str {
        owned.v
    }
}

fn str_to_key(s: &str) -> Key { 
    Key { v: s }
}

struct Node<'a> {
    children: HashMap<Key<'a>, Box<Node<'a>>>
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn add_str(&mut self, s: &'a str) {
        self.add_iter(s.split('.').map(str_to_key))
    }

    fn add_iter<I>(&mut self, mut i: I) where I: Iterator<Item = Key<'a>> { //'
        if let Some(key) = i.next() {
            let noderef =
                match self.children.entry(key) {
                    Vacant(e) => {
                        let n = Node { children: HashMap::new() };
                        e.insert(Box::new(n))
                    }
                    Occupied(e) => {
                        e.into_mut()
                    }
                };
            noderef.add_iter(i);
        }
    }

    fn lookup_str(&self, s: &str) -> bool {
        self.lookup_iter(s.split('.').map(str_to_key))
    }

    fn lookup_iter<'b, I>(&self, mut i: I) -> bool where I: Iterator<Item = Key<'b>> {
        if let Some(key) = i.next() {
            match self.children.get(key.v) {
                Some(node_box_ref) => node_box_ref.lookup_iter(i),
                None => false
            }
        } else {
            true
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut node: Node<'static> = Node { children: HashMap::new() }; //'
    node.add_str("one.two.three");
    { // <-- "inner scope"
        let s = String::from_str("one.two.three");
        println!("lookup: {:?}", node.lookup_str(&*s));
    }
    println!("The End");
}
```

As you can see, I deliberately made `node` a `Node<'static>`, so the node's lifetime parameter `'a` actually refers to the lifetime of the whole program. It's OK in this example because the only string slice it will store is a string literal. Note that for the lookup I created a short-lived `String` object. So, the lifetime parameter `'b` in `node.lookup_str` will refer to the "inner scope" which is obviously shorter than `'a='static`. And it all works out! :)

Oh, I also got rid of the iterator boxing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I suspect I'm still a little fuzzy on what exactly `'a` denotes here. Consider the code at this (modified) playpen: http://is.gd/fEkekL. Clearly, the iterator and its items don't live as long as the `Node` instance lifetime, which is what I thought `'a` denoted. Yet this compiles. What am I overlooking?

Comment: @Ray: I'm not sure I understand the question. But I'm almost sure that this playpen code snippet is not really what you want. I just realized what you are actually trying to achieve here. Let me get back to you later.

Comment: @Ray: Please have a look at my updated answer. I think, it should solve your problem just fine – that is, as long as you still want to stick to HashMaps storing references to string slices (which surely led you to this level of complexity)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sellibitze! I've accepted the answer. I did have a question regarding your last sentence, though. It seems like you're implying there's a better design that avoids the complexity. Is there? FWIW, the `Key` definition I provided was oversimplified for illustration purposes. The real `Key` is `enum Key { A(String), B(String) }` and I was hoping to use something equivalent but with `&str` for querying (I have no idea if that's at all possible).

Comment: @Ray: If you make the `HashMap` store `String` keys instead of something like `&str`, things will automatically get easier and less constrained at the cost of additional allocations for all the `String`s' buffers. And thanks to `BorrowFrom` you can still directly pass a `&str` via `get`. So, for the lookup, you could still benefit from string slices in the sense of avoiding unnecessary String allocations.

Comment: If you want to use `enum Key { A(String), B(String) }` as key type and be able to query the map with a `&str` then you can do that by implementing `BorrowFrom<Key>` for `str`. I just don't see the point in this A/B thingy. You might have to be careful about `Key` and `&str` both being hashable in a compatible way.

Comment: What I was getting at was potentially using something like `enum KeyRef { A(&str), B(&str) }` for lookup. I'm assuming I can use `BorrowFrom` here, as well. The use case is something more like (but not actually) `enum Shoe { Men(String), Women(String) }` where the string is the shoe model name, assuming that the same model name can have a men's and women's variant.

Comment: @Ray: Do, do you want Men(x) to always be a different key than Woman(y) regardless of x and y? If so, you could not use `str` for lookup, because it will hash differently and lack the Men/Woman distinction.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the diagnostics are less-than-ideal. I would recommend that a bug is filed; perhaps that suggester doesn't know about lifetimes in associated types yet.

To fix your problem, I'd suggest using the same lifetime that you are already holding:

```
impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn lookup(&self, mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = Key<'a>>>) -> bool { //'
        match iter.next() {
            Some(key) => match self.children.get(&key) {
                             Some(node) => node.lookup(iter),
                             None => false
                         },
            None => true
        }
    }
}
```

I actually am unclear what your original code was trying to do. You define a new lifetime parameter `'b`. That lifetime will be determined *by the caller* for each call made. That's bad news, because that lifetime might last longer than the `Node` itself, leading to references to memory that are no longer valid. Yay! Rust saved us!

Another solution would be to have an explicit lifetime `'b`, but inform Rust that it's <s>shorter or equal to than `'a` (said "a outlives b")</s> longer than or equal to `'a` (said "b outlives a"):

```
fn lookup<'b : 'a>(&self, mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = Key<'b>>>) -> bool
```

#### Further exposition

Here's a smaller example that shows the same problem:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn example<'a, 'b>(set: HashSet<&'a u8>, key: &'b u8) -> bool {
    set.contains(&key)
}

fn main() {}
```

Similarly, if you setup a relationship between the lifetimes (`<'a, 'b : 'a>`) or make both parameters the same lifetime, then this code will compile.

Both [`HashSet::contains`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.contains) and [`HashMap::get`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) lookup the key by taking a reference to the key type (or something that can [lend out a reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.BorrowFrom.html) to the key type). However, the key that you are looking up must be the same type (or subtype) that you have stored. In this case, the type *also includes the lifetime*. That's why using the same lifetime (or one that outlives the key) allows it to compile.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to tie `'b` to `'a` here. There are no references held to `iter` or any of the items in it in a `Node` instance. Why wouldn't it be sufficient for the lifetime of `iter` and the items to just be the scope of `lookup` itself?

Comment: Also, according to https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0192-bounds-on-object-and-generic-types.md, `\`b : \`a` implies that b outlives a, not the other way around. So saying that is akin to saying that the keys used for look-up are guaranteed to live longer than the node, which isn't the case.

Comment: Ugh. I always get that mixed up when I talk about it, thanks for the correction. I've added a bit more exposition to my answer, maybe that helps explain a bit?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That "the type also includes the lifetime" is the key insight I was missing. However, I've got to admit I find the consequences baffling. Is there really no way to see if a container contains a key without the key living as long as the container? Isn't that fairly limiting? And also, what is the "conflicting requirement" the compiler talks about?